# what does the notation $(x,y)^2$ mean in the representation $F(x,y) \equiv x+y \mod (x,y)^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series

Let us consider the power series in two variables $F(x,y)$ over a field $F$ such that $F(x,y)$ converges for $x,y \in U \subset F$.

Then what does $(x,y)^2$ in the representation $$F(x,y) \equiv x+y \mod (x,y)^2$$ mean here?

Does it mean " we are taking modulo by the $\text{term}$ generated by $x,y$ ?

i.e., Is $(x,y)^2=g(x,y)$ a function of $x,y$ ?

or is it that $x^2, y^2, x^2y^2, x^2y^4, x^4y^2, x^4y^4, \cdots \in (x,y)^2$ ?

For example, if we take $F(x,y)=x+y+x^2+y^2+x^2y^2+x^4y^2+x^2y^4+\cdots$, then $$F(x,y) \equiv x+y \mod (x,y)^2.$$

Am I right?

Comment: I don't think this is standard notation.  I would interpret as saying "modulo quadratic terms".  Thus, in particular,  I would say that $xy\equiv 0 \pmod {(x,y)^2}$, for instance.  But I am not sure this matches the authors' intent.

Comment: @Sil, No, it is not like that. I am sure

Comment: @lulu, rather I think $(xy)^2 \equiv 0 \mod (x,y)^2$ because terms will be square

Comment: It's congruence modulo the square of the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$. That is, as lulu suggested, modulo terms of degree $\geqslant 2$, only the constant and linear terms are considered.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR  I certainly agree that $x^2y^2$ would be $\equiv 0$, but I believe that all the quadratic terms, including $x^2, y^2, xy$, are likewise $0$.

Comment: @lulu, yes you right perhaps.  I also mentioned the same in my question above